# .htaccess rewrite between three servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like to copy the same htaccess file to three different servers. However I don't want to update the contents each time I do that. How do I make the domain name be detected 'dynamically'?

For example, I have the following:

```
Redirect 301 /test/directory/page.php http://examplesite.com/original/location.php
```

This won't work on the other two domains because, obviously, they have different urls.

Should I modify like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/directory/page.php /original/location.php [R=301,L]
```

Or is there a better way where I don't have to specify the domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will work (with one small change -- see notes):

```
RewriteRule ^test/directory/page.php /original/location.php [R=301,L]
```

You can also use this (in case you need to change protocol from current HTTP or HTTPS to a specific one):

```
RewriteRule ^test/directory/page\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/original/location.php [R=301,L]
```

**NOTES:**

1. `%{HTTP_HOST}` = current domain name. So if accessed `http://examplesite.com/test/directory/page.php` then `%{HTTP_HOST}` will have `examplesite.com` as its value.
2. No need for leading slash `/` after `^` (unless rule will be placed in config file and not .htaccess). For example: when accessing `http://examplesite.com/test/directory/page.php` the `RewriteRule` will work with `test/directory/page.php`.